# Repeat value with closer neighbor different from zero until value change

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, rolling-computation

I have a data box with about 30 million records, categorized by ID and opened by date.

I need to distribute the value of the closest row of a column in the number of previous dates, I have already tried using the rolling function using windows paramter, but unfortunately the number by which I must distribute is variable (I mean, it can be 12, 6, 7, ...) and this parameter does not accept variables from the same df.

works fine, but the 12 number can be variable:

```
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=12)
df['REPEAT_AMOUNT'] = df['AMOUNT'].rolling(window, min_periods=1).sum()
```

I try to change the number of window_size by using the variable in my df:

```
df['REPEAT_AMOUNT'] = df['AMOUNT'].rolling(window=df['VARIABLE_DISTRIBUTION'].astype(int), min_periods=1).sum()
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: window must be an integer
```

And added to the above, the difference in months to the first record may not have the same date numbers as the subsequent ones.

This I currently have:

```
+----+-----------------------+------------+---------+
| ID | VARIABLE_DISTRIBUTION |    DATE    |  AMOUNT |
+----+-----------------------+------------+---------+
|  1 |                    12 | 30-04-2021 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-05-2021 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 30-06-2021 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-07-2021 |     100 |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-08-2021 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 30-09-2021 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-10-2021 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 30-11-2021 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-12-2021 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-01-2022 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 28-02-2022 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-03-2022 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 30-04-2022 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-05-2022 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 30-06-2022 |       - |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-07-2022 |     150 |
|  2 |                     8 | 30-04-2021 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-05-2021 |     200 |
|  2 |                     8 | 30-06-2021 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-07-2021 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-08-2021 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 30-09-2021 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-10-2021 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 30-11-2021 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-12-2021 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-01-2022 |     300 |
|  2 |                     8 | 28-02-2022 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-03-2022 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 30-04-2022 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-05-2022 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 30-06-2022 |       - |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-07-2022 |       - |
+----+-----------------------+------------+---------+
```

And that's what i want:

```
+----+-----------------------+------------+----------+----------------+
| ID | VARIABLE_DISTRIBUTION |    DATE    |  AMOUNT  |  REPEAT_AMOUNT |
+----+-----------------------+------------+----------+----------------+
|  1 |                    12 | 30-04-2021 |       -  |            100 |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-05-2021 |       -  |            100 |
|  1 |                    12 | 30-06-2021 |       -  |            100 |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-07-2021 |     100  |            100 |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-08-2021 |       -  |            150 |
|  1 |                    12 | 30-09-2021 |       -  |            150 |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-10-2021 |       -  |            150 |
|  1 |                    12 | 30-11-2021 |       -  |            150 |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-12-2021 |       -  |            150 |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-01-2022 |       -  |            150 |
|  1 |                    12 | 28-02-2022 |       -  |            150 |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-03-2022 |       -  |            150 |
|  1 |                    12 | 30-04-2022 |       -  |            150 |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-05-2022 |       -  |            150 |
|  1 |                    12 | 30-06-2022 |       -  |            150 |
|  1 |                    12 | 31-07-2022 |     150  |            150 |
|  2 |                     8 | 30-04-2021 |       -  |            200 |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-05-2021 |     200  |            200 |
|  2 |                     8 | 30-06-2021 |       -  |            300 |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-07-2021 |       -  |            300 |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-08-2021 |       -  |            300 |
|  2 |                     8 | 30-09-2021 |       -  |            300 |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-10-2021 |       -  |            300 |
|  2 |                     8 | 30-11-2021 |       -  |            300 |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-12-2021 |       -  |            300 |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-01-2022 |     300  |            300 |
|  2 |                     8 | 28-02-2022 |       -  |              - |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-03-2022 |       -  |              - |
|  2 |                     8 | 30-04-2022 |       -  |              - |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-05-2022 |       -  |              - |
|  2 |                     8 | 30-06-2022 |       -  |              - |
|  2 |                     8 | 31-07-2022 |       -  |              - |
+----+-----------------------+------------+----------+----------------+
```

I appreciate any help with the window Parameters or any other kind of solution.

sorry for non-native english

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use [`groupby bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-bfill):

```
df['REPEAT_AMOUNT'] = df.groupby('ID')['AMOUNT'].bfill()
```

`df`:

```
    ID  VARIABLE_DISTRIBUTION        DATE AMOUNT REPEAT_AMOUNT
0    1                     12  30-04-2021    NaN           100
1    1                     12  31-05-2021    NaN           100
2    1                     12  30-06-2021    NaN           100
3    1                     12  31-07-2021    100           100
4    1                     12  31-08-2021    NaN           150
5    1                     12  30-09-2021    NaN           150
6    1                     12  31-10-2021    NaN           150
7    1                     12  30-11-2021    NaN           150
8    1                     12  31-12-2021    NaN           150
9    1                     12  31-01-2022    NaN           150
10   1                     12  28-02-2022    NaN           150
11   1                     12  31-03-2022    NaN           150
12   1                     12  30-04-2022    NaN           150
13   1                     12  31-05-2022    NaN           150
14   1                     12  30-06-2022    NaN           150
15   1                     12  31-07-2022    150           150
16   2                      8  30-04-2021    NaN           200
17   2                      8  31-05-2021    200           200
18   2                      8  30-06-2021    NaN           300
19   2                      8  31-07-2021    NaN           300
20   2                      8  31-08-2021    NaN           300
21   2                      8  30-09-2021    NaN           300
22   2                      8  31-10-2021    NaN           300
23   2                      8  30-11-2021    NaN           300
24   2                      8  31-12-2021    NaN           300
25   2                      8  31-01-2022    300           300
26   2                      8  28-02-2022    NaN           NaN
27   2                      8  31-03-2022    NaN           NaN
28   2                      8  30-04-2022    NaN           NaN
29   2                      8  31-05-2022    NaN           NaN
30   2                      8  30-06-2022    NaN           NaN
31   2                      8  31-07-2022    NaN           NaN
```